# How to calculate the sum of all rows at each new row in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, datagrid

My app is a sort of cash register for a shop so in the datagrid there is Reference,it is the reference of the product.
When the user types the reference directly the information about the product will be filled in the other columns and the user can choose the quantity he wants and it will do the calculation.

 The sum is done but if I click on another row I am having this error : `System.InvalidCastException` and the error come to this `sum += Convert.ToInt32(TAB_Credit.Rows[i].Cells["Total"].Value);` and this is the comment : `{"Unable to cast a DBNull object in other types."}`
Also, I tried to put the total of the bill in the datagrid...

`Reference | Product |Quantity |Price |Total |Total Bill
AB         |AB       |2      |1000    |2000  |5000 <--my task is to find this
BC         |BC       |3      |1000    |3000`

```
private void TAB_Credit_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < TAB_Credit.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {

        sum += Convert.ToInt32(TAB_Credit.Rows[i].Cells["Total"].Value);
    }

    TAB_Credit.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Total_Bill"].Value = sum.ToString();
}
```

Comment: `DBNull` means that `Total` column is `NULL` and you are trying to convert it value to `int`. Can you ensure that total is always filled?

Comment: how I can do it ?

Comment: In debugger i think.

Comment: How do you get your data from MySQL?
Can you provide a query?

Comment: `string cmdText = @"SELECT * FROM tb_ajout_articles 
                            WHERE Reference=@ref";
         MySqlDataAdapter sa = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdText, MyConnexion);
         sa.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ref", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value =
         TAB_Credit.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Reference"].Value.ToString();`

Comment: What's inside `tb_ajout_articles`? Does it contain column `Total`?

Comment: yes, but here I am not getting the total I only insert it in the datagrid

Comment: When you click on new row, all values inside it are empty. Maybe you need to iterate over `TAB_Credit.Rows.Count - 1` instead of `TAB_Credit.Rows.Count`?

Comment: you are right ! Is it possible that it only shows the total not at each line ! I mean if you see the example in my case the first line in the total Bill there is 2000 and the second line 5000 but I want to be as I described in the question

Comment: Just don't display the `Total` column if you don't like to see it. Under the table in your user interface add some label and put calculated total inside it.

Comment: It will be the same Event ? RowValidated ?

Comment: Yes I think you can put code here.

Comment: You  saw the example that I gave in my question ? the total bill I want to show it but in only one row

Comment: Then just do `TAB_Credit.Rows[TAB_Credit.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["Total_Bill"].Value = sum.ToString();`

Comment: I put this: `TAB_Credit.Rows[0].Cells["Total_Fact"].Value = sum.ToString();` Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put
`TAB_Credit.Rows[TAB_Credit.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["Total_Bill"].Value = sum.ToString();`

inside `RowValidated` event.